# scons configure: scons command not found

Tags: scons

I installed scons.zip first, then did the "python setup.py install --user" command to install scons and it said,

```
Installed SCons library modules into 
/Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/lib/scons-3.0.1
Installed SCons scripts into /Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/bin
Installed SCons man pages into /Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/man/man1
```

but when i try to run

```
scons configure
```

it doesn't work and says,

```
scons: command not found
```

what am i doing wrong here

Comment: is /Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/bin in your path? is that where the scons script is installed?  Any reason you're not installing via virtualenv and pip ?

Comment: I did use pip instead and got this.   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scons ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/jacklee/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d2/d6/7a/2c1ae29f2a2f69727e7b0e91fc7d170d84cd6b261792ce44e4
Successfully built scons


Installing collected packages: scons Successfully installed scons-3.0.1

Comment: shouldnt scons script be installed into /Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/bin like it says?

Comment: Is it not there?

Comment: sorry how do i check if it's there? I'm a beginner.

Comment: ls -l /Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/bin/

Comment: yes, i see scons, scons-configure-cache, scons-time, sconssign.

Comment: is /Users/jacklee/Library/Python/2.7/bin in your PATH ? (echo $PATH) which scons